# How to write a C Program which can convert Volwels in the given string to lower if it were upper and upper if it were lower?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char input[50];
    char i;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(input, 50 , stdin);

    for (j = 0; input[i] != '\0'; j++)      
        if (input[i]=='a'||input[i]=='e'||input[i]=='i'||input[i]=='o'||input[i]=='u')
        {
            input[i]=toupper(input[i]);
            printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);
        }

         else if (input[i]=='A'||input[i]=='E'||input[i]=='I'||input[i]=='O'||input[i]=='U')
        {
            input[i]=tolower(input[i]);
            printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

This is not my **Home work** .I am a **beginner** in C .I can not find out the mistake in my code i have **googled** it but cant locate any useful data that could correct my mistake.The ERROR i am getting is printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);---->this line is not performing any action  and i appreciate if someone would correct my mistake.

INPUT-please enter a sentence
       I am a beginner in c

Desired OUTPUT- Your new sentence is:i Am A bEgInnEr In c

ACTUAL OUTPUT  - //empty line//

Thanks

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing? What *specifically* are you asking for help with?

Comment: I think you Jed where you shoulda Ied, or vice-versa.  In particular, you never assign any value to `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the other answer says, you want to use i, not j.... you will also want to put {} in your for.  Then move your printf .......  you could make it simpler as an extended exercise :)

```
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)      
{
        if (input[i]=='a'||input[i]=='e'||input[i]=='i'||input[i]=='o'||input[i]=='u')
        {
            input[i]=toupper(input[i]);
        }

         else if (input[i]=='A'||input[i]=='E'||input[i]=='I'||input[i]=='O'||input[i]=='U')
        {
            input[i]=tolower(input[i]);

        }
}
   printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is wrong:

```
for (j = 0; input[i] != '\0'; j++)
```

Should be:

```
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

There is no need for the `j` variable, as you never use it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth xoring `0x20` will toggle the case of a letter, look at the set bits of upper and lower case letters in the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). This is also a good time for you to familiarize yourself with the standard library. The `strchr` function would let you greatly simplify your code:

```
for(i=0; str[i]; i++)
    if(strchr("aeiouAEIOU", str[i]))
        str[i] ^= 0x20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that's funny.  This could only be homework.

```
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
```